# Trouble calling the print function of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2012, inheritance

I've been really stumped by some homework I am working on.

I am working on a function called "boxFactory" that returns a pointer of the Box base class to the testing class. The testing class then calls the print function from that pointer.

Right now I'm trying to get checkered box printing before I work on the other types. However, when I run the code below, an exception is thrown at bptr->print(os) that reads:

"Unhandled exception at 0x0091C512 in Assignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD0."

```
Box * boxFactory(char c, int w, int h){

Box * b;

if(c == 'c')
{
    CheckeredBox cb; 
    b = &cb;
    b->setHeight(h);
    b->setWidth(w);

    return b;
}

return NULL;
}
```

Code snippet from the test class:

```
Box * bptr = boxFactory('c',5,3);

// Check print #7
os.str(""); //reset output holder
bptr->print(os);
t.test(os.str() == "x x x\n x x \nx x x\n", "print 5x3 checkered box from factory");
```

The print function from the derived Checkered class:

```
ostream& CheckeredBox::print(ostream& os) const
{
//HEIGHT for loop
for (int i = 0; i < height_; i++)
{
bool isX; //is current space x or blank

//makes the every other line starts
if (i % 2 == 0) 
{
    isX = true;
}
else
{
    isX = false;
}

//WIDTH for loop
for (int c = 0; c < width_; c++)
{
    if (isX) //utilizes isX boolean
    {
        os << "x";
        isX = false; //oscilates bool between spaces
    }
    else
    {
        os << " ";
        isX = true; //continues oscilation
    }
}

os << "\n"; //append new line after each row
}

return os;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable. This is undefined behaviour.

```
if(c == 'c')
{
    CheckeredBox cb; 
    b = &cb;
    b->setHeight(h);
    b->setWidth(w);

    return b;
}
```

Here `cb` goes out of scope once the function leaves this `if` but you return its address. Using this address results in "Undefined behavior". You instead want to allocate an object on the heap and then return that. Something like the below.

```
    b = new CheckeredBox();
```

Comment: But don't forget to `delete` b: C++ will not do this automatically. Or look at `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3):

You created an automatic instance of CheckeredBox object in boxFactory function. So when the cb object goes out of the scope (if block), it will be destructed and you are returning the address of a destroyed object. That's why when you try to call print method of this pointer you get 'Access Violation' error. Here is what you can do to accomplish what you want.

You need to construct CheckeredBox object on heap using new keyword then return it from boxFactory Function. In this case your application will work but the problem remains who should delete the object you created on the heap. You could specify in your function documentation that the caller should delete returned object but it's very likely that your application leaks memory if you or someone else using your code isn't careful enough.
You could use std::auto_ptr to take and transfer ownership of your object so it will be deleted automatically.

```
std::auto_ptr<Box> boxFactory(char c, int w, int h){
  std::auto_ptr<Box> b;

  if(c == 'c')
  {
      CheckeredBox *cb = new CkeckeredBox(); 
      cb->setHeight(h);
      cb->setWidth(w);
      b.reset(cb);
  }

  return b;
}
```

Considering auto_ptr is deprecated in new C++11 standard you could use boost::shared_ptr, std::unique_ptr(C++11 only) or std::shared_ptr(C++11 only).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(c == 'c')
{
  CheckeredBox cb; 
  b = &cb;
  b->setHeight(h);
  b->setWidth(w);

  return b;
}
```

Local variables get allocated in the stack, when the code block they are declared is exited the same memory space will be used for other variables that will overwrite them.

For dynamically allocation of objects, use `new` operator, which will allocate the objects in the *heap*. These objects will be available until you `delete` them (do not forget to do so, because otherwise you will get *memory leaks*)

```
b = new CheckeredBox();
// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having a few problems with fully understanding how memory works.